# Can't sign a dig sig utilizing java / keytool

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509certificate, keytool

I have created a certificate basically straight from the keytool example page:

> keytool -genkey -dname "cn=Anything, ou=Anything, o=Anything, c=US" -alias business -keypass kpi135 -keystore C:\mykeystore -storepass ab987c -validity 1095

I am trying to access this certificate and use the private key portion to digitally sign a portion of text to authenticate with a third party.  Below is the code I'm attempting:

```
   //Add bouncyCastle as a provider
   Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
   keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\mykeystore"), "ab987c".toCharArray());
   Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA", "BC");
   PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("business", "kpi135".toCharArray()); //Exception here
   sig.initSign(privateKey);
   sig.update("myUID__myNonce".getBytes());
   byte[] digitalSignature = sig.sign();

   System.out.println("Signature Formulated: " + digitalSignature);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.provider.DSAPrivat
eKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKDigestSignature.engineInitSign(Unkno
wn Source)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1095)
        at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:480)
        at MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:15)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:28)
```

I assume it's because I've somehow created the certificate with the wrong type of key, but I'm not sure I'm finding what I need by digging through the keytool page.  It *does* mention that you can apparently generate a key using -keysig RSA and -sigalg RSA however when I try those flags when creating a certificate I get:

```
keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA Signature not availab
le

enter code here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it seems you can add "-keyalg RSA" to the keygen command which alleviates the mismatch issue.  I was incorrectly trying both -keyalg and -sigalg in the same keygen command.  The code above now executes without exceptions.